# Firebase: error: unknown option `--public'

Tags: unix, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am using [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#2) tutorial, after I successfully login to Firebase, I need to set the root dir. So as the tutorial instructs, I run:

`~/firebase-webchat$ firebase init --public .`

However, I get the following error:

> error: unknown option `--public'

Does anyone know what command I should be using?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I`ve having the same issue, but i finally get a answer for me.

First of all, do you will net logout from your firbase cli login, so lets run:

```
$ firebase logout
```

So thats should logout you.

So next lets login again, but at this time, we will need accept the follow question from firebase cli.

```
$ firebase login --no-localhost
? Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage information? Yes
```

If the ask from firebase not appears, just run

```
$ firebase login --reauth --no-localhost
```

**So before continue, lets make some improvement on our directory structure, put all your files inside directory called "public"**

So to the GRAND FINALE, just run

```
$ firebase init
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `firebase init --public .` -> you're probably following the same tutorial I was. Just use `firebase init`. You'll get asked to set your public directory later.

`=== Hosting Setup
Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.
? What do you want to use as your public directory? .`

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

After updating Node JS, i was able to deploy the project. 
You can try the same by updating Node JS:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Not sure but after updating the node.js, i was able to select project from terminal and able to deploy the project using this commands:

```
firebase deploy
```

You can set project from terminal too.

```
firebase deploy -project your-project-id
```